# unicode and python issue (access to unicde code charts)

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, unicode-string, python-unicode

Yesterday i wrote the following `function` to convert `integer` to `Persian` :

```
def integerToPersian(number):
    listedPersian = ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹']
    listedEnglish = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']    
    returnList = list()

    listedTmpString = list(str(number))

    for i in listedTmpString:
        returnList.append(listedPersian[listedEnglish.index(i)])

    return ''.join(returnList)
```

When  you call it such as : `integerToPersian(3455)` ,  it `return ۳۴۵۵`,
`۳۴۵۵` is equivalent to `3455` in `Persian` and `Arabic language`.When you read
a number such as reading from `databae`, and want to show in `widget`, this
`function` is very useful.

I downloaded `codes charts`  of `unicode` from http://unicode.org ,Because i need to wrote `PersianToInteger('unicodeString')` According to it should get `utf-8` as parameter and `utf-8` store `2 bytes`,Also i'm newbie in pytho.

**My questions** are, how can store `2bytes`? , how can `utf8` store , how can split an `unicode string` to another format ? how can use `unicode code charts`?

**Notes:** I found to use `int() built-in fuinction` , but i couldn't use it.may be you can

Comment: Are you using python2 or python3?

Comment: Note that Python comes with all the information from the Unicode charts built-in (and they're guaranteed to match the version of Unicode your Python version works with) in the `unicodedata` module.

Comment: As a side note, `listedEnglish.index(i)` is intended to be just `int(i)`, right? Which is a lot simpler, and means you can get rid of `listedEnglish` entirely…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to read the Python Unicode HOWTO for either Python [2.x](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) or [3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), as appropriate. But I can give you brief answers to your questions.

> My questions are, how can store 2bytes? how can utf8 store , how can split an unicode string to another format ?

A `unicode` object holds characters; a `bytes` object holds bytes.

Note that in Python 2.x, `str` is the same thing as `bytes`; in 3.x, it's the same thing as `unicode`. And in both languages, a literal with neither a `u` nor a `b` prefix is a `str`. Since you didn't tell us whether you're using Python 2 or 3, I'll use explicit `unicode` and `bytes`, and `u` and `b` prefixes, everywhere.

You convert between them by picking an encoding (in this case, UTF-8) and using the `encode` and `decode` methods. For example:

```
>>> my_str = u'۰۱'
>>> my_bytes = b'\xdb\xb0\xdb\xb1'
>>> my_str.encode('utf-8') == my_bytes
True
>>> my_bytes.decode('utf-8') == my_str
True
```

If you have a UTF-8 `bytes` object, you should `decode` it to `unicode` as early as possible, and do all your work with it in Unicode. Then you don't have to worry about how many bytes something takes, just treat each character as a character. If you need UTF-8 output, `encode` back as late as possible.

(Very occasionally, the performance cost of decoding and encoding is too high, and you need to deal with UTF-8 directly. But unless that really is a bottleneck in your code, don't do it.)

So, let's say you wanted to adapt your `integerToPersian` to take a UTF-8 English digit string instead of an integer, and to return a UTF-8 Persian digit string instead of a Unicode one. (I'm assuming Python 3 for the purposes of this example.) All you need to do is change `str(number)` to `number.decode('utf-8')`, and change `return ''.join(returnList)` to `return ''.join(returnList).encode('utf-8')`, and that's it.

> how can use unicode code charts?

Python already comes with the Unicode code charts (and the right ones to match your version of Python) compiled into the [`unicodedata`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) module, so usually it's a lot easier to just use those than to try to use the charts yourself. For example:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.digit(u'۱')
1
```

---

> … i need to wrote PersianToInteger('unicodeString')

You really shouldn't need to. Unless you're using a very old Python, `int` should do it for you. For example, in 2.6:

```
>>> int(u'۱۱')
11
```

If it's not working for you, `unicodedata` is the easiest solution:

```
>>> numeral = u'۱۱'
>>> [unicodedata.digit(ch) for ch in numeral]
[1, 1]
```

However, either of these will convert digits in *any* script to a number, not just Persian. And there's nothing in the Unicode charts that will directly tell you that a digit is Persian; the best you can do is parse the name:

```
>>> all('ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT' in unicodedata.name(ch) for ch in numeral)
True
>>> all('ARABIC-INDIC DIGIT' in unicodedata.name(ch) for ch in '123')
False
```

---

If you really want to do things in either direction by mapping digits from one script to another, here's a better solution:

```
listedPersian = ['۰','۱','۲','۳','۴','۵','۶','۷','۸','۹']
listedEnglish = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']    
persianToEnglishMap = dict(zip(listedPersian, listedEnglish))
englishToPersianMap = dict(zip(listedEnglish, listedPersian))

def persianToNumber(persian_numeral):
    english_numeral = ''.join(persianToEnglishMap[digit] for digit in persial_numeral)
    return int(english_numeral)
```

Comment: If you read agian, my `integerToPersian` work fine, i need to help for `persianToInteger`.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh: If you would actually answer people's questions instead of writing the same comment over and over, it would be much easier to help you.