# Python: Detect number separator symbols and parse into a float without locale

Tags: python, formatting, python-2.x

I have a dataset with millions of text files with numbers saved as strings and using a variety of locales to format the number. What I am trying to do is guess which symbol is the decimal separator and which is the thousand separator.

This shouldn't be too hard but it seems the question hasn't been asked yet and for posterity it should be asked and answered here.

What I do know is that there is always a decimal separator and it is always the last non[0-9] symbol in the string.

As you can see below a simple `numStr.replace(',', '.')` to fix the variations in decimal separators will conflict with the possible thousand separators.

I have seen ways of doing it if you know the locale but I do **NOT** know the locale in this instance.

**Dataset:**

```
1.0000 //1.0
1,0000 //1.0
10,000.0000 //10000.0
10.000,0000 //10000.0
1,000,000.0000 // 1000000.0
1.000.000,0000 // 1000000.0

//also possible

1 000 000.0000 //1000000.0 with spaces as thousand separators
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach:

```
import re
with open('numbers') as fhandle:
    for line in fhandle:
        line = line.strip()
        separators = re.sub('[0-9]', '', line)
        for sep in separators[:-1]:
            line = line.replace(sep, '')
        if separators:
            line = line.replace(separators[-1], '.')
        print(line)
```

On your sample input (comments removed), the output is:

```
1.0000
1.0000
10000.0000
10000.0000
1000000.0000
1000000.0000
1000000.0000
```

#### Update: Handling Unicode

As NeoZenith points out in the comments, with modern unicode fonts, the venerable regular expression `[0-9]` is not reliable.  Use the following instead:

```
import re
with open('numbers') as fhandle:
    for line in fhandle:
        line = line.strip()
        separators = re.sub(r'\d', '', line, flags=re.U)
        for sep in separators[:-1]:
            line = line.replace(sep, '')
        if separators:
            line = line.replace(separators[-1], '.')
        print(line)
```

Without the `re.U` flag, `\d` is equivalent to `[0-9]`.  [With that flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re-syntax), `\d` matches whatever is classified as a decimal digit in the Unicode character properties database.  Alternatively, for handling unusual digit characters, one may want to consider using [`unicode.translate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626238/how-to-convert-normal-numbers-into-arabic-numbers-in-django/26627977#26627977).

Comment: Thank you works a treat. Although I did uncover in the dataset there are also integers. So straight after the `re.sub()` I make sure the `len(separators) > 0`. Nice design pattern stripping out valid characters to leave a foreign symbol array.

Comment: Your welcome.  And, I just updated the code to handle that case.

Comment: For ongoing posterity and keeping this answer up to date it would seem I have run into issues with Arabic-Indic numerals. As per this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6479605/622276) the regex `'\d'` rather than `'[0-9]'` should be used. Also the SO:ans (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1676590/622276) helps explain why there are two Arabic-Indic sets of digits. Then this SO:ans (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26627977/622276) suggests using the `unicode.translate()` method to map arabic-indic digits to european digits.

Comment: @NeoZenith Thank you.  I just updated the answer for unicode.

Comment: Outside this question of parsing separator symbols, I am converting the final string to a usable `float` value. This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/18707237/622276) points to the fact that if you have `u'\u0669\u0663.\u0660'` ( a `unicode` data type as opposed to a `str` data type) then the `float()` will cast the unicode digits to `93.0` avoiding the need to `unicode.translate()` to european digits first.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that also checks for wrong number formatting, notifies of possible wrong interpretation, and is faster than the current solution (performance reports below):

```
import re

pattern_comma_thousands_dot_decimal = re.compile(r'^[-+]?((\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)|(\d*))(\.|\.\d*)?$')
pattern_dot_thousands_comma_decimal = re.compile(r'^[-+]?((\d{1,3}(\.\d{3})*)|(\d*))(,|,\d*)?$')
pattern_confusion_dot_thousands = re.compile(r'^(?:[-+]?(?=.*\d)(?=.*[1-9]).{1,3}\.\d{3})$')  # for numbers like '100.000' (is it 100.0 or 100000?)
pattern_confusion_comma_thousands = re.compile(r'^(?:[-+]?(?=.*\d)(?=.*[1-9]).{1,3},\d{3})$')  # for numbers like '100,000' (is it 100.0 or 100000?)


def parse_number_with_guess_for_separator_chars(number_str: str, max_val=None):
    """
    Tries to guess the thousands and decimal characters (comma or dot) and converts the string number accordingly.
    The return also indicates if the correctness of the result is certain or uncertain
    :param number_str: a string with the number to convert
    :param max_val: an optional parameter determining the allowed maximum value.
                     This helps prevent mistaking the decimal separator as a thousands separator.
                     For instance, if max_val is 101 then the string '100.000' which would be
                     interpreted as 100000.0 will instead be interpreted as 100.0
    :return: a tuple with the number as a float an a flag (`True` if certain and `False` if uncertain)
    """
    number_str = number_str.strip().lstrip('0')
    certain = True
    if pattern_confusion_dot_thousands.match(number_str) is not None:
        number_str = number_str.replace('.', '')  # assume dot is thousands separator
        certain = False
    elif pattern_confusion_comma_thousands.match(number_str) is not None:
        number_str = number_str.replace(',', '')  # assume comma is thousands separator
        certain = False
    elif pattern_comma_thousands_dot_decimal.match(number_str) is not None:
        number_str = number_str.replace(',', '')
    elif pattern_dot_thousands_comma_decimal.match(number_str) is not None:
        number_str = number_str.replace('.', '').replace(',', '.')
    else:
        raise ValueError()  # For stuff like '10,000.000,0' and other nonsense

    number = float(number_str)
    if not certain and max_val is not None and number > max_val:
        number *= 0.001  # Change previous assumption to decimal separator, so '100.000' goes from 100000.0 to 100.0
        certain = True  # Since this uniquely satisfies the given constraint, it should be a certainly correct interpretation

    return number, certain
```

Performance in worst case:

```
python -m timeit "parse_number_with_guess_for_separator_chars('10,043,353.23')"
100000 loops, best of 5: 2.01 usec per loop

python -m timeit "John1024_solution('10.089.434,54')"
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.04 usec per loop
```

Performance in best case:

```
python -m timeit "parse_number_with_guess_for_separator_chars('10.089')"       
500000 loops, best of 5: 946 nsec per loop

python -m timeit "John1024_solution('10.089')"       
100000 loops, best of 5: 1.97 usec per loop
```