# How to convert normal numbers into arabic numbers in django

Tags: python, django

I have a list of numbers [1,2,3,....]

Now i want to convert them into arabic numbers using django.

Is it possible? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: convert to what ? and use where ?

Comment: The list of numbers you've given are [Arabic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_numerals)

Comment: They are already arabic numbers.

Comment: do you want string representation of numbers?

Comment: This list was having the normal numbers. But in arabic they have different numbers right like '٠','١','٢','٣','٤','٥','٦','٧','٨','٩'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this function:

```
def enToArNumb(number): 
    dic = { 
        0:'۰', 
        1:'١', 
        2:'٢', 
        3:'۳', 
        4:'۴', 
        5:'۵', 
        6:'۶', 
        7:'۷', 
        8:'۸', 
        9:'۹', 
        .:'۰', 
    }
    return dic.get(number)
```

and use it like this:

```
ar_numbers = [enToArNumb(num) for num in numbers]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```py
ar_num = '۰١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'
en_num = '0123456789'

table = str.maketrans(en_num, ar_num)

normalized = "643256284534".translate(table)
print(normalized)
```

The output:

```py
٦٤٣٢٥٦٢٨٤٥٣٤
```

Comment: This is best way worked for me

Answer (score 2):

To convert a (unicode) string of digits to an equivalent "Arabic-Indic" digit you can use `unicode.translate()`:

```
arabic_indic_trans = dict(
    zip((ord(s) for s in u'0123456789'),
        u'\u0660\u0661\u0662\u0663\u0664\u0665\u0666\u0667\u0668\u0669')
)

>>> for s in u'0123456789', u'33342353', u'88192838743':
...     print('{!r} -> {!r}'.format(s, s.translate(arabic_indic_trans)))
u'0123456789' -> u'\u0660\u0661\u0662\u0663\u0664\u0665\u0666\u0667\u0668\u0669'
u'33342353' -> u'\u0663\u0663\u0663\u0664\u0662\u0663\u0665\u0663'
u'88192838743' -> u'\u0668\u0668\u0661\u0669\u0662\u0668\u0663\u0668\u0667\u0664\u0663'
```

This should work in Python 2 and 3.

To convert from an integer, first convert the integer to a unicode string, then translate:

```
>>> for s in 1234567890, 33342353, 88192838743876487602873545683470:
...     s = unicode(s)    # Python 2 (s = str(s) for Python 3)
...     print('{!r} -> {!r}'.format(s, s.translate(arabic_indic_trans)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the translation is done for Middle East region, since Hassan's answer uses a numerals that are **close** to the standard Arabic numerals but not the same.

```py
def en_to_ar_num(number_string):
    dic = {
        '0': '۰',
        '1': '١',
        '2': '٢',
        '3': '۳',
        '4': '٤',
        '5': '۵',
        '6': '٦',
        '7': '۷',
        '8': '۸',
        '9': '۹',
    }

    return "".join([dic[char] for char in number_string])

en_to_ar_num("124") # ١٢٤
```

Answer (score 0):

According to shakram02 answer you can do this to translate English number to Arabic one if they have dash or in string:

```
def en_to_ar_num(number_string):
   lis=[]
   dic = {
          '0': '۰',
          '1': '١',
          '2': '٢',
          '3': '۳',
          '4': '٤',
          '5': '۵',
          '6': '٦',
          '7': '۷',
          '8': '۸',
          '9': '۹',
   }

   for char in number_string:
          if char in dic:
                 lis.append(dic[char])
          else:
                 lis.append(char)
   return "".join(lis)
```

Print:

```
print(en_to_ar_num("124-25-abc"))
```

Output:
[i screen it cause it wasn't appear like this in my post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAcU4.png)