# How to change english numbers to persian/arabic numbers in python

Tags: python, django, unicode

+1 9956755308

how to change this mobile number to persian or arabic numbers with unicode

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Comment: You can do this using the accepted answer provided[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626238/how-to-convert-normal-numbers-into-arabic-numbers-in-django).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with translating:

```py
arabic = '۰١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩'
english = '0123456789'

translation_table = str.maketrans(english, arabic)

translated_num = "+1 9956755308".translate(translation_table)
```